# The two spend the night with each other

Tags: traduction, verbes-pronominaux

> Les deux passent la nuit ensemble.

or

> Les deux se passent la nuit ensemble.

I was always confused on the difference between using *se* or *ensemble*.

Comment: Incidentally, *Les deux se passent la nuit ensemble* does not seem like something a native speaker would say.

Comment: @Relaxed Because this is not a grammatically correct sentence. *Les deux passent la nuit ensemble* would be a correct sentence.

Comment: @Sifu “se passer” does exist (*une heure se passe*, *ils se passent le sel*) and the sentence is therefore grammatically perfectly acceptable. It just makes no sense in this context, which was my point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je traduirais par :

> Ils passent tous les deux la nuit ensemble.

Answer (score 5):

I think an easier way to understand the difference between *se* and *ensemble* would be with a simpler sentence :

> Ces personnes *se* mangent. **AND** Ces personnes mangent *ensemble*.

They would translate respectively to :

> These people are eating themselves (or… each other). **AND** These people are eating together.

Does that help?

Comment: Well, there's one more meaning to “ils se mangent”: *Ces gâteaux, ils se mangent* (one can eat them).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez mais les gens ? à moins de le dire à des anthropophages.

Comment: @Laure Bien... un humain est.. mangeable, à proprement parler. Mais, d'un autre côté, on ne pourrait pas dire "*<del>Ces gâteaux mangent ensemble</del>*"

Comment: @Laure: Dans les deux premiers cas on a aussi affaire à de l'anthropophagie, je n'introduis rien de nouveau en ce qui concerne ce point.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Enfin.. Cela pourrait aussi avoir une connotation sexuelle, mais c'était loin d'être le but de cette réponse! Si vous avez une meilleure idée de verbe pouvant avoir une distinction claire, je placerai ma réponse en "community wiki" et je vous laisserai l'y mettre.

Answer (score 1):

Quite often « se » means « self ». So you can think that it stands for object of action:

```
il         se      laver  ->   he        wash   himself
subject    object  verb        subject   verb   object
```

Well, the translation is rough, but it's aimed to be illustrative ;-)

Another use of « se » is to express idea of return action, consider this example:

> ils s'écrivent  ->  they write to each other

Also « se » may be used to create passive voice constructions:

> il se vend  ->  il est vendu  ->  it is sold